# Sorting Java List using Map Values

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary

I have a  `Map` and a `List`. The `List` should be sorted based on the `Map` key values. E.g:

```
Map = (<2,"Andy">,<4,"Karl">)
List = ("Kathy","Andy","Yiri","Jun","Karl")
```

I have to sort the List in such a way that at index : (2 : Andy) should be there 
and at index (4 : Karl) should be there. For rest of elements order does not matter.
Rest of Conditions are :

1. Entries in Map may or may not present in List ;(In this we can keep the order same)
2. List could be empty
3. Map could be empty

I am able to do this in 2 loops , I was curious to know if it is possible to achieve this in a single Loop.

Comment: Still not clear to me, could you show us the code?

Comment: Two questions: a) Is this homework? b) In the Map, which is the key and which is the value? In `<2, "Andy">`, is "2" the key or the value?

Comment: No its not a home work :) , I was able to serve the purpose of the requirement but felt there can a be better solution.    Yes 2 here is the key  Value on which I am sorting is String element

Comment: WHy do not use TreeMap with wrapper object as a value. Still it will be nlogn, NOT O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 1 loop to loop through all keys in the map, and search for the object in the List with `indexOf(Object)`, then use `set` twice to swap the object to the correct position.

Pseudocode (that looks like Java):

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e: entrySet) {
    int index;
    if ((index = list.indexOf(e.getValue())) >= 0 && index != e.getKey()) {
        list.set(index, list.set(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Well, complexity is not that good: O(nk) where n is the number of elements in the List and k is the number of elements in the Map.

Comment: ya, using indexOf is a way of hiding a LOT of iterations through the List, but with the key/value being backwards for usefulness in this situation, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: Reconstructing a Map is another NlogN function, though.

Comment: @BillJames: The complexity is not everything. Many linear searches on the List may be even slower than a one time O(nlog n) reverse mapping plus one traversal through the List (this can be achieved by: if we swap with an element ahead of the current element, we will do the swapping, but we will not advance the "pointer"). Edit: Lol, I didn't even notice that you are not the OP. x_x

Comment: Ya, I'm a lurker on this one.  Talking about algorithmic complexity lures me in.